# Form submitted only in Firefox, working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two identical form with the same flow, call a function, the function performs an ajax POST and print the result in a `<p>` tag, one of the form however is being submitted only on Firefox, while it works as intended on Chrome. The other form works fine on both browsers but both forms are identical.

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="dopostback()">
    <!-- form controls here -->      
    <p id="msg"></p>          
    <button type="submit">Send</button>                                             
</form>
```

the function called is like this one:

```
function dopostback(){
    if (document.myForm.checkValidity()){
        // here collect relevant data and do a $.ajax POST
        // the result end up in a <p> tag above the submit button
    }

    return false; //IMPORTANT: this prevents the form from being submitted, tested on the other form
}
```

the only real difference I can think of is that the form working on both browsers has the `dopostback()` inside a `.js` file (after jQuery of course, in both cases) the other form has the script inside the page, so not including an external `.js` file, again the script is after the jQuery, on Firefox this form is submitted on Chrome it is not, but both are pretty much doing the same.

Comment: Try: `onsubmit="return dopostback()"`

Comment: You might want to `onsubmit="return dopostback()"` to explicitly make the method return return to the inline event handler, but other than that, dunno.

Comment: dumb of me! Thank you guys, that did the trick :)

Comment: Just as an appendix to the already said: `onsubmit="dopostback" *should* work as well ;)

Comment: @WolverinDEV it works but still submits the form